# php xdebug on max sierra not working

Tags: xdebug

On Mac Sierra:

I've got php 7.1 installed, and installed xdebug via:

brew install php71-xdebug

Xcode is 8.0

php -v
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
PHP 7.1.0RC3 (cli) (built: Oct  2 2016 01:05:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

With a phpinfo() I cannot find any text that says xdebug

The php.ini file I've tried several variations of: and restarted apache

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1    # Not safe for production servers
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

More details can be found here: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1354

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP7.1 is current not supported by xdebug, (php version <7.1). you should use 7.0 instead, and don't forget to turn on xdebog.remote_enable